# ECS "Select a valid deployment group for the service." CodeDeploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, yaml, amazon-ecs, aws-code-deploy

i am running a an error "Select a valid deployment group for the service." when i try to do a blue/green deployment on my ecs service. (https://monosnap.bugsmasher.online/marcoschmiedel/20200716192812untnf_.png)

Can anybody tell me what a "valid deployment group" is all about?

Heres my environment as yaml file....

Thx for the help...

```
#
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
# AWS TEMPLATE VERSION
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# FIRST WE DECLARE THE CLOUDFORMATION TEMPLATE VERSION SO THAT THE COMPILER 
# WORK WITH THE CORRECT SYNTAX.
#
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'



#
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
# PARAMETERS
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# WE SET GLOBAL PARAMETERS FOR BETTER HANDLING OF THE YAML FILE. THESE CAN 
# BE EASILY ADJUSTED IF NECESSARY.
#
Parameters:

  #
  # APPSLUG IS DECLARED AS AN IDENTIFIER FOR THIS CLOUD FORMATION STACK.
  # IT IS USED IN MOST OF THE RESOURCES (E.G. TAGS) FOR BETTER 
  # DIFFERENTIATION.
  #
  
  AppSlug:
    Type: String
    Default: "polaris-1337"
    
  #
  # THE WILDCARD SUBDOMAIN * .ITMAXCLOUD.COM WAS MANUALLY DEFINED FOR ALL 
  # ENVIRONMENTS. THE ASSOCIATED SSL CERTIFICATE MUST BE REFERENCED WITHIN 
  # THIS CLOUD FORMATION STACK.
  #
  
  WildcardDomain:
    Type: String
    Default: "itmaxcloud.com"  
  SSLCert:
    Type: String
    Default: "arn:aws:acm:eu-central-1:643325912344:certificate/b4df1ca3-6a5b-476e-8bd1-cec600ea6dc8"
  
  #
  # ????? CODE DEPLOY ARN
  #
  
  CodeDeployArn:
    Type: String
    Default: "arn:aws:iam::643325912344:role/CodeDeploy"
    
#
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
# RESOURCES
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# RESOURCES ARE THE BUILDING BLOCKS THAT MAKE UP THE ENVIRONMENT.
#  
Resources: 

  #------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # NETWORK
  #------------------------------------------------------------------------
  
  #
  # VPC
  # A VPC (VIRTUAL PRIVATE CLOUD) IS LIKA A VIRTUAL CONTAINER IN WHICH ALL 
  # OUR NETWORKS ARE LOCATED.
  #
  
  Vpc:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties: 
      CidrBlock: '10.0.0.0/16'
      EnableDnsHostnames: "true"
      EnableDnsSupport: "true"
      InstanceTenancy: "default"
      Tags: 
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub "${AppSlug}-vpc"
          
  #
  # SUBNET
  # SUBNETS ARE THE ACTUAL PHYSICAL NETWORKS WITHIN THE VPC. THESE ARE 
  # LOCATED IN THREE DIFFERENT AVAILABILITY ZONES.
  #
  
  SubnetAlpha:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId:
        Ref: Vpc
      CidrBlock: '10.0.10.0/24'
      AvailabilityZone: !Sub "${AWS::Region}a"
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: !Sub "${AppSlug}-alpha"
  SubnetBeta:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId:
        Ref: Vpc
      CidrBlock: '10.0.20.0/24'
      AvailabilityZone: !Sub "${AWS::Region}b"
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: !Sub "${AppSlug}-beta"
  SubnetGamma:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId:
        Ref: Vpc
      CidrBlock: '10.0.30.0/24'
      AvailabilityZone: !Sub "${AWS::Region}c"
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: !Sub "${AppSlug}-gamma"
        
  #
  # INTERNET GATEWAY
  # AN INTERNET GATEWAY IS JUST ANOTHER NETWORK IN OUR VPC. IT HAS A SIMILAR 
  # STATUS LIKE A SUBNET AND OFFERS "THE INTERNET AS A NETWORK".
  #
  
  InternetGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::InternetGateway
  InternetGatewayAttachement:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref 'Vpc'
      InternetGatewayId: !Ref 'InternetGateway'
      
  #
  # ROUTE TABLE
  # THE ROUTE TABLE IS THE ORCHESTRATOR IN OUR VPC. IT DECIDES WHO 
  # COMMUNICATES WITH WHOM.
  #
  
  RouteTable:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref 'Vpc'  
      
  #
  # ALL NETWORKS MUST BE ASSOCIATED WITH THE ROUTE TABLE.
  #
  
  RouteInternetGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    DependsOn: InternetGatewayAttachement
    Properties:
      DestinationCidrBlock: '0.0.0.0/0'
      GatewayId: !Ref 'InternetGateway'
      RouteTableId: !Ref 'RouteTable'
  RouteSubnetAlpha:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref SubnetAlpha
      RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTable
  RouteSubnetBeta:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref SubnetBeta
      RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTable
  RouteSubnetGamma:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref SubnetGamma
      RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTable

  #------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # LOAD BALANCER
  #------------------------------------------------------------------------

  #
  # SECURITY GROUP
  # THE LOAD BALANCER GETS A SECURITY GROUP THAT ONLY ALLOWS DESIRED 
  # PORTS (E.G. 80 OR 443).
  #
  
  SecurityGroupPublicLoadBalancer:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: !Sub "${AppSlug}-public-loadbalancer-security"
      GroupName: !Sub "${AppSlug}-public-loadbalancer-security"
      VpcId: !Ref 'Vpc'
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - Description: !Sub "${AppSlug}-public-loadbalancer-security-http"
          IpProtocol: tcp
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
          FromPort: 80
          ToPort: 80
        - Description: !Sub "${AppSlug}-public-loadbalancer-security-https"
          IpProtocol: tcp
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
          FromPort: 443
          ToPort: 443
      Tags: 
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub "${AppSlug}-public-loadbalancer-security"
          
  #
  # LOAD BALANCER
  # A LOAD BALANCER SERVES AS A BASTION BETWEEN THE VPC NETWORK AND THE 
  # OUTSIDE WORLD. IT CONTROLS THE TRAFFIC OF THE ECS CLUSTER.
  #
  
  PublicLoadBalancer:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer
    Properties:
      Scheme: internet-facing
      LoadBalancerAttributes:
      - Key: idle_timeout.timeout_seconds
        Value: '30'
      Subnets:
        - !Ref SubnetAlpha
        - !Ref SubnetBeta
        - !Ref SubnetGamma
      SecurityGroups: [!Ref 'SecurityGroupPublicLoadBalancer']
      Tags: 
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub "${AppSlug}-public-loadbalancer"
          
  #
  # LOAD BALANCER LISTENER
  # A LOAD BALANCER CAN REGISTER ONE LISTENER PER PORT. THIS LISTENER 
  # CAN BE EQUIPPED WITH VARIOUS RULES THEN. (IN OUR CASE WE EQUIP 
  # THE STANDARD PATH FROM PORT 80 WITH A REDIRECT TO 443. THE STANDARD 
  # PATH OF PORT 443 RETURNS THE HTTP ERROR 400.)
  #
  
  HttpListenerPublicLoadBalancer:
   Type: "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener"
   Properties:
     DefaultActions:
       - Type: "redirect"
         RedirectConfig:
           Protocol: "HTTPS"
           Port: "443"
           Host: "#{host}"
           Path: "/#{path}"
           Query: "#{query}"
           StatusCode: "HTTP_301"
     LoadBalancerArn: !Ref PublicLoadBalancer
     Port: 80
     Protocol: "HTTP" 
  HttpsListenerPublicLoadBalancer:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
    Properties:
      DefaultActions:
      - Type: fixed-response
        FixedResponseConfig:
          StatusCode: 400
      LoadBalancerArn: !Ref PublicLoadBalancer
      Port: '443'
      Protocol: HTTPS
      Certificates:
        - CertificateArn: !Sub "${SSLCert}"
        
  #------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # ECS
  #------------------------------------------------------------------------
  
  #
  # ECS CLUSTER
  # THE ECS CLUSTER MANAGES THE PROVISION OF VARIOUS SERVICES (E.G. DOCKER 
  # CONTAINERS). WITH FARGATE, THERE IS NO NEED TO MAINTAIN EC2 HARDWARE
  # ANY LONGER.
  #
  
  EcsCluster:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Cluster
    Properties: 
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: !Sub "${AppSlug}-ecs"
        
  #------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # CodeDeploy
  #------------------------------------------------------------------------
  
  #
  # ?
  #
       
  CodeDeploy:
    Type: AWS::CodeDeploy::Application
    Properties:
      ApplicationName: !Sub "${AppSlug}-code-deploy"
      ComputePlatform: Lambda
      
  CodeDeployDeploymentGroup:
    Type: 'AWS::CodeDeploy::DeploymentGroup'
    Properties:
      ApplicationName: !Ref CodeDeploy
      DeploymentConfigName: CodeDeployDefault.LambdaAllAtOnce
      DeploymentStyle:
        DeploymentType: BLUE_GREEN
        DeploymentOption: WITH_TRAFFIC_CONTROL
      ServiceRoleArn: !Sub "${CodeDeployArn}"     
           
  #------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # WEBAPP CONTAINER
  #------------------------------------------------------------------------
  
  #
  # TASK
  # A TASK IS A JOB THAT WE WANT TO RUN. IN THE CASE OF ECS AND FARGATE, 
  # THIS PART CONSISTS PARAMETERS FOR DOCKER AND THE FARGATE SERVER 
  # HARDWARE.
  #
  
  TaskWebapp: 
    Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
    Properties: 
      ContainerDefinitions: 
        # DOCKER PARAMETERS
        - Name: !Sub "${AppSlug}-webapp-container"
          Image: "httpd:latest"
          PortMappings: 
            - ContainerPort: 80
              Protocol: "tcp"
          StartTimeout: 60
      # FARGATE PARAMETERS
      Cpu: "256"
      Memory: "512"
      RequiresCompatibilities: 
        - "FARGATE"
      NetworkMode: "awsvpc"
      Tags: 
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub "${AppSlug}-webapp-task"   
           
  #
  # SECURITY GROUP
  # THE CONTAINER NEEDS A SECURITY GROUP WITH WHICH IT CAN BE REACHED 
  # FROM THE LOADBALANCER.
  #
  
  SecurityGroupWebapp:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties: 
      GroupDescription: !Sub "${AppSlug}-webapp-security"
      GroupName: !Sub "${AppSlug}-webapp-security"
      SecurityGroupIngress: 
        - Description: !Sub "${AppSlug}-webapp-security-http"
          IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 80
          ToPort: 80
          SourceSecurityGroupId: !Ref SecurityGroupPublicLoadBalancer
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc
      Tags: 
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub "${AppSlug}-webapp-security"
          
          
          
  #
  # TARGET GROUP
  # ?????
  #          
  TargetGroupBlueWebapp:
    Type: 'AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup'
    Properties:
      HealthCheckIntervalSeconds: 5
      HealthCheckPath: /
      HealthCheckPort: '80'
      HealthCheckProtocol: HTTP
      HealthCheckTimeoutSeconds: 2
      HealthyThresholdCount: 3
      Matcher:
        HttpCode: '200'
      Port: 80
      Protocol: HTTP
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: !Sub "${AppSlug}-webapp-target-blue"
      TargetType: ip
      UnhealthyThresholdCount: 4
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc           
 
  TargetGroupGreenWebapp:
    Type: 'AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup'
    Properties:
      HealthCheckIntervalSeconds: 5
      HealthCheckPath: /
      HealthCheckPort: '80'
      HealthCheckProtocol: HTTP
      HealthCheckTimeoutSeconds: 2
      HealthyThresholdCount: 3
      Matcher:
        HttpCode: '200'
      Port: 80
      Protocol: HTTP
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: !Sub "${AppSlug}-webapp-target-green"
      TargetType: ip
      UnhealthyThresholdCount: 4
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc             



      
  # Regelwerk für listener
  ListenerRuleWebapp:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::ListenerRule
    Properties: 
      Actions:
        - Type: forward
          ForwardConfig:
            TargetGroups:
              - TargetGroupArn: !Ref TargetGroupBlueWebapp
                Weight: 1
              - TargetGroupArn: !Ref TargetGroupGreenWebapp
                Weight: 2
      Conditions: 
        - Field: host-header
          HostHeaderConfig:
            Values:
              - !Sub "webapp.${WildcardDomain}"
      ListenerArn: !Ref HttpsListenerPublicLoadBalancer
      Priority: 1


       
  #
  # ECS SERVICE
  # ?????
  # 
  ServiceWebapp:
    DependsOn: HttpsListenerPublicLoadBalancer
    Type: AWS::ECS::Service
    Properties: 
      Cluster: !Ref EcsCluster
      DeploymentController: 
        Type: "CODE_DEPLOY"
      DesiredCount: 2
      LaunchType: "FARGATE"
      LoadBalancers: 
        -   ContainerName: !Sub "${AppSlug}-webapp-container"
            ContainerPort: 80
            TargetGroupArn: !Ref TargetGroupBlueWebapp
        -   ContainerName: !Sub "${AppSlug}-webapp-container"
            ContainerPort: 80
            TargetGroupArn: !Ref TargetGroupGreenWebapp
      NetworkConfiguration: 
         AwsvpcConfiguration:
          AssignPublicIp: "ENABLED"
          SecurityGroups:
            - !Ref SecurityGroupWebapp
          Subnets: 
            - !Ref SubnetAlpha
            - !Ref SubnetBeta
            - !Ref SubnetGamma
      # PropagateTags: "TASK_DEFINITION"
      SchedulingStrategy: "REPLICA"
      TaskDefinition: !Ref TaskWebapp

      
      
      
      


  # DNS ?
  myDNSOne:
    Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSetGroup
    Properties:
      HostedZoneName: itmaxcloud.com.
      Comment: some comments maybe?.
      RecordSets:
      - Name: webapp.itmaxcloud.com.
        Type: CNAME
        TTL: '900'
        SetIdentifier: Some Identifiery here
        Weight: '1'
        ResourceRecords:
        -  !GetAtt PublicLoadBalancer.DNSName
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using ECS, but your CodeDeploy applicattion is set to `Lambda`. It should be **set to ECS**:

```
  CodeDeploy:
    Type: AWS::CodeDeploy::Application
    Properties:
      ApplicationName: !Sub "${AppSlug}-code-deploy"
      ComputePlatform: ECS # <-- NOT Lambda
```

There could be more issues, but the incorrect `ComputePlatform` is the most apparent one.